# Select React Component data option not appeard

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am facing an issue with representing data inside select-react Component, I had successfully getting data form server side (node js ) by componentDidMount()

```
  componentDidMount(){
      fetch('api/transporationTypes') 
      .then( res => res.json())
      .then(trasnportation => this.setState({trasnportation }, () => console.log(trasnportation)));

    }
```

but I cannot set loaded data inside React-Select Component I tried the below here below how this component works with static data.

```
 render() {
    const { selectedOption } = this.state;

    return (
      <Select
        name="form-field-name"
        value={selectedOption}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        options={[
          { value: 'one', label: 'One' },
          { value: 'two', label: 'Two' },
        ]}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

but when I trying to load dynamic data with code below it represent No results Found see screenshot:  http://prntscr.com/jqvp76.

alos printing the data via console.log('optionItems',optionItems) in dev tools print correctly http://prntscr.com/jqvq7v
How can I make option of select component works successfully

```
render() {
    const { selectedOption } = this.state.selectedOption;
    let optionItems = this.state.trasnportation.map((trans) =>
   [ {value: `${trans.TransportationType}` , label :  `${trans.TransportationType}`}]
);
console.log('optionItems',optionItems)
    return (
      <div className="row">
        <h1>Choose Tranportation Type</h1> 
      <Select className="col-md-8" 
      name="form-field-name"
      value={selectedOption}
      onChange={this.handleChange1}
      option={optionItems}
      placeholder = "Select one of below"/>
    </div>
    );

  }
}
```

Thanks -- Fadi

Comment: const { selectedOption } = this.state.selectedOption;

Is this the problem? You are attempting to destructure a property that doesn't exist?

Maybe you need: const { selectedOption } = this.state; ?

Comment: no , option={optionItems} this is the property that I am trying to fill and it is not working as expected.

Comment: shouldn't it be `options`? : `options={optionItems}`

Answer (score 0):

The items have wrong type:

```
    let optionItems = this.state.trasnportation.map((trans) =>
       [ {value: `${trans.TransportationType}` , label :  `${trans.TransportationType}`}] 
    );
```

to

```
let optionItems = this.state.trasnportation.map((trans) =>
    ({value: `${trans.TransportationType}` , label :  `${trans.TransportationType}`}) 
); // [] -> ()
```

Comment: I am still getting an error after changing it with the. please look at screenshot above,http://prntscr.com/jqz35q

Answer (score 0):

It likely has something to do with the typos, in the code supplied there is:

- `trasnportation`
- `transporation`
- `transportation`

Comment: Questions caused by typos are off-topic for SO. Commenting and voting to close are both appropriate; answering is not.